# Is there a way to run virt-manager on Windows?

Tags: windows, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

We've been using KVM for almost a year strictly on CentOS 5.x as the KVM host, with Fedora and Ubuntu workstations accessing the KVM host and its guests using virt-manager, virt-viewer, and ssh.

Is anyone aware of a way to access the KVM host using virt-manager from a Windows workstation? We have one co-worker who would like to access the KVM host, from a Win7 system.

**EDIT #1**

I'm familiar with running a X11 server on windows such as [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/), and remote displaying virt-manager from the KVM host to a windows workstation, but what I'd really like here is to know of any solutions native to windows, i.e. is there a version of virt-manager that'll run on windows.

**EDIT #2**

Still no progress on this myself wrt. a native virt-manager client. I did come across a compiled version of libvirtd for windows along with a discussion on a mailing list about how to get libvirtd working on windows. I'm adding the links to this question in the hopes that someone will figure out how to get virt-manager working.

- [virt-manager for windows forum thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.emulators.virt-tools/916)
- [libvirtd for windows](http://libvirt.org/windows.html)

**EDIT #3**

Finally *some* progress. Came across this project on github called [msys_setup](https://github.com/photron/msys_setup) which includes a windows port of virt-manager. It's partially functional, doesn't support qem+ssh:// connection type so it's still not usable for our needs, but it's a start.

Answer (score 12):

Use putty and some X Server software on the Windows side (e.g. [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/)) and use X11 tunneling with putty to display the remote virt-manager console.

Comment: I am using the same approach currently. But the problem is any special keys (like winkey or other windows-wide keyboard shortcuts that I have configured) are grabbed by host windows, instead of the virt-manager window.

Answer (score 11):

I would use Cygwin.
Then you can install virt-manager and openssh and place a shortcut on the Desktop.
It is native.

Cygwin provides the linux tools and facilities around programs so that it feels like a linux environment. For instance, virt-manager can call ssh to make the connection to your KVM Server and would be able to run virsh and send commands to it. It also provides an X-Server.
Which is all natively compiled.

**Update:** Thanks Yaakov's comment: There is now a directly installable package in cygwin for virt-manager. The actions below are not necessary anymore.

If you have the time:
You can easily customize the cygwin installation to exactly fit your needs. Just go through the folders, throw everything out you don't need. Write a script that starts the X Server and then virt-manager, zip it up and ey presto! there's your virt-manager for Windows.

Comment: I've used cygwin in the past and though this would work is a little too heavy handed a solution for what I was looking for. AS I said in the question, I'm looking for a native client for windows to virt-manager.

Comment: Cygwin now includes a virt-manager package as well.

Comment: Does this has better performance than WSL?

Comment: Update: Since 2023 the packages for virt-manager won't install on cygwin as they're not updated and require python2 which doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I would simply use ssh (putty) and virsh, and a VNC/Spice client (like [virt-viewer for Windows](https://virt-manager.org/download/)), if I were confined to a Windows workstation

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Spice. Can you explain what Spice is and is there a Spice client available for windows? I found this link, http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/SPICE, which shows how to set it up, but it doesn't really explain the benefits of Spice vs. VNC.

Comment: I also found this link to the [Spice Project](http://spice-space.org/home.html). Still don't quite entirely grasp exactly where it fits. I _think_ that it provides a native graphics driver for the guests, but that's as far as I've gotten in my understanding.

Comment: Spice performs better and delivers a much better (actually, at the level of a normal, non-3D video card, meaning you can watch movies and youtube flicks, play non-3D games etc.) performance than VNC. Clients are available from several platforms. You have to start the VM with Spice support and install a Spice driver in the VM of course. At the moment, RHEL5 and higher and Fedora 14 and higher both have native support for Spice

Comment: Curious, can the Spice driver be used for the KVM host itself or is it limited to KVM guests only?

Comment: Spice is built into qemu, so currently it can only be used with KVM guests

Answer (score 5):

Here is a up-to-date instruction set performed by me today and saved here for my future reference:

1. Install [wsl and ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WSL)
2. Install [XMing](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/)
3. Start Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
4. Install dbus-x11 and virt-manager: `sudo apt install dbus-x11 virt-manager`
5. (optional) If you need ssh

   1. Install ssh-askpass: `sudo apt install ssh-askpass` and
   2. Generate a new ssh key, if you have not done so: `ssh-keygen`
   3. Copy the key to your servers: `ssh-copy-id user@server`
6. Start Xming
7. run `virt-manager`

The first error is not a problem, just add a new connection and remove the local connection and you are up and running. If your connections are not saved between starts of the virt-manager, you need to perform the dbus session.conf trick:

Edit the configuration file: `sudoedit /etc/dbus-1/session.conf` and edit the first line or add the line such that the file contains:

```
 <listen>tcp:host=localhost,port=0</listen>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use Bash on Ubuntu on Windows ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about ).

Then, you are able to install `virt-manager` as on Ubuntu:

```
$ apt-get install virt-manager
```

Then you'll need a X server. You can install Xming.

You'll need to add `DISPLAY=:0.0` to your environment. To do that, add `export DISPLAY=':0.0'` to `~/.bashrc` and restart your terminal.

You may want to enable a ssh agent:

```
eval `ssh-agent` ; ssh-add
```

After that, you should be able to run virt-manager as you'll do on Linux. There are some bugs but it works :-).

edit by a z:
d-bus error? 
Per: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4rsmzp/bash_on_windows_getting_dbus_and_x_server_working/
Run: 
`sudo sed -i 's$<listen>.*</listen>$<listen>tcp:host=localhost,port=0</listen>$' /etc/dbus-1/session.conf`

close/open bash, try again, use virt-manager --debug for more info

Comment: This would have possibly been my choice, except I can't get Bash on LTSB Windows 10. Also, you can't backup Windows 10 Store Apps.. REDICULOUS!  https://superuser.com/questions/1295577/backing-up-and-restoring-microsoft-store-apps-windows-10

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  There is virt-viewer for Windows

http://virt-manager.org/download/sources/virt-viewer/

Update:

I see you were asking about virt-manager on windows and not virt-viewer.

Comment: +1 I was trying to use virt-viewer as virt-manager lol, thanks for saving me the time! It isn't clear on the website that its not the manager.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a "HowTo" on [AndreasT Answer](https://serverfault.com/a/451479/312793) as it is the "best option" IMO ATM. Although using Bash + Windows Subsystem for Linux might be another option, it was unavailable on Windows 10 LTSB and I really hate how [I can't backup Windows 10 Store Apps](https://superuser.com/questions/1295577/backing-up-and-restoring-microsoft-store-apps-windows-10), so it would need to be re-configured/install each time Windows was deployed.

I posted a YouTube Video here >> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDEAu3oPcR0

And I wrote up my own blog post, but I know better than to leave out the details in a URL so I will copy the short form here. (https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/wiki/running-virt-manager-inside-windows-10-using-cygwin-with-shortcut-on-desktop-28016650.html)

- Install Cygwin w/ `virt-manager`, `xinit` and `openssh`.
- Configure passwordless SSH via RSA Key to KVM Host.
- Configure XWin to autostart Virt-Manager.

  ```
  cat << 'EOF' > ~/.startxwinrc
  export DISPLAY=:0.0
  virt-manager
  sleep inf
  EOF
  chmod +x ~/.startxwinrc
  ```

Create shortcut on Desktop: Virt-Manager.cmd
This is the contents of mine:

```
tskill.exe xwin

C:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c /usr/bin/startxwin
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using XMing

here is a snapshot of running SSH with X11 forwarding on Xming and virt-manager working on windows (X11 forwarded)

[image: snapshot of virt-manager with x11 forwarding on xming]

#### References

- http://blog.allanglesit.com/2011/03/linux-kvm-managing-kvm-guests-using-virt-manager-on-windows/
- http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/run_any_gnu_linux_app_on_windows_without_any_virtualization
- http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/

Comment: This relies on running virt-manager on a remote host, which is not what is wanted here.

Comment: hmmm in that case a straight answer to the question OP asks is a no because I have not encountered any solution which would run a virt-manager on a Windows 7 machine other than the X11 forwarding techniques available to us

Comment: Read my "EDITS" in the question. I mentioned a couple of leads that looked promising wrt. to running virt-manager on windows. It is working, just not for our scenario as of yet.

Answer (score -1):

virt-manager is now available natively on Windows: https://virt-manager.org/download/

Comment: It looks like only virt-viewer for Windows is available at that URL.